navigate multiple pages in Chrome Console
I have some code which clicks through a website and downloads some data. But when I try to run it in chrome console, as soon as the browser navigates to the next website, the code halts.
How can I fix this?
document.getElementById("LOB").value="CA"
document.getElementById("LOB_State").value="MI"
document.getElementById("Effective_Range").value="0"
document.getElementById("Effective_Month").value="12"
document.getElementById("Effective_Day").value="1"
document.getElementById("Effective_Year").value="2024"
fillTables()
   
//wait for page to load
    
document.getElementsByName("File")[1].checked = true
document.getElementsByName("submitButton")[0].click()

Code can't get past here because the 'click' causes a new page to load.
//wait for page to load
    
document.getElementById("downloadbutton").click()
document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[3].click()
    
//wait for page to load


The javascript you have written for one page will be completely reloaded when the DOM is rendered for the new page. It would likely be easier to use an external scripting language for what you're trying to do, eg. python with the selenium library would be much better suited for this goal.

@AustinDuling Damn, I may well be screwed then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78674688/vba-or-python-packages-for-web-scraping

I can't quite tell from the post you've linked there - did you try what one commenter proposed by setting up a virtual environment on your work computer and installing all the required packages under that virtual environment? Or has your work vetoed all external python packages and the chrome driver? From the post/comments it's unclear if you gave it a try or not.

So far no luck with the virtual environment but could just be me, I haven't used them before. I can install the packages to python but don't have permission to run "python -m virtualenv" within cmd. And I can't install chrome drivers

I finally had luck with selenium. The trick was just to use "pip install --user selenium" instead of "pip install selenium" and the access issues went away. Doh

If you're trying to automate a process you do often, consider making a simple Chrome extension.  Might be easier than setting up a Python web driver to do it for you.
